# Why are my Array Values being cut off in my DB?

Tags: php, database

For some reason my array values are being cut off in my DB. Here is my php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","Andrew","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, modelid, system, department, comm,    other, shift, comments)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[modelid]','". implode(",",       $_POST['system']) ."','$_POST[department]','". implode(",", $_POST['comm']) ."','".   implode(",", $_POST['other']) ."','$_POST[shift]','$_POST[comments]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What I mean by cutoff is that my checkbox entries are being entered properly, separated by commas and all, but its almost as if there is some sort of character limit that I can enter into a single field. Just messing around I've added the mysql_real_escape_string in with no errors thinking that was the problem, but I still have the same issue. Has anyone seen this before or aware of any possible fixes?

Comment: Maybe the row length ?  What is your row length ?

Comment: Check your database, a character limit is probably the cause of this. If it's longer than 255 chars, use `text` instead of `varchar`.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Oh wow I feel like a newbie, you guys are right I had the length/value set at 15!! Thanks for the advice but it crossed my mind as soon as I posed the question, you guys are quick though!!! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, better not user `mysql_*` functions - better use PDO or MySQLi.

the problem in your code is here:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, modelid, system, department, comm,    other, shift, comments)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[modelid]','". implode(",",       $_POST['system']) ."','$_POST[department]','". implode(",", $_POST['comm']) ."','".   implode(",", $_POST['other']) ."','$_POST[shift]','$_POST[comments]')";
```

1. You should sanitize and validate the POST parameters before using them
2. If you would do #1, you could use parameters like `$firstname` without string concatenation (which has a missing `"` before and after the first 3 POST parameters.

The way I would implement this is something like:

```
   /*** first sanitize your POST params ***/
   $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']));
   $lastname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']));
   //etc ...

   /**the query ***/
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, modelid, system, department, comm,    other, shift, comments)
VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :modelid, :system, :department, :comm, :other, :shift, :comments)");


   /*** bind the paramaters ***/
   $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   // etc...

   /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
   $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You guys are light years ahead of me!!! I'm currently switching between LAMP and WAMP, to make use of mysqli will I have to update my stacks or does it just work since mysql is already in use?? I definitely plan on hardening the code, I just wanted to get something that worked first and go from there, I'm just learning on my own so its somewhat slow going.

Comment: @AndrewGillium if you installed PHP version > 5.0 (which you probably have) then you have support both for PDO and MySQLi. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ohh wow, I definitely feel like a newbie now!!! I had my length/value set at 15!! I should have looked around a bit more before asking this question but thanks to all who commented!!!